# jQuery not loading when converting Bootstrap template to Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

The jQuery files will not load from a Bootstrap template. I am converting it into a Wordpress theme. I have tried many different way of enqueuing scripts in my functions.php file. I have tried de-registering jQuery but to no avail.

Chrome dev tools gives a 404 error and filed to load js files..

```
<?php 
  function willow_rivers_files() {
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_theme_file_uri('vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-files', get_theme_file_uri('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-style-from-template', get_theme_file_uri('css/grayscale.min.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', get_theme_file_uri('style.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('google-font-round', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round');
    wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts-nunito', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i');  

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri('vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-easing', get_template_directory_uri('vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-easing', get_template_directory_uri('js/grayscale.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
  }

  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'willow_rivers_files');
?>
```

Comment: As i reacall, `get_template_directory_uri()` does not accept any parameters - so it should be done like `wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js', NULL, '1.0', true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has it's own jquery library you no need to include it separately.

To load jquery from WP you need to just add dependency of jquery library in your JS enqueue's third Parameter.

Please give a try as follows:

1. Remove :

`wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri('vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);`

2. for following two lines change it from

`wp_enqueue_script('jquery-easing', get_template_directory_uri('vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-easing', get_template_directory_uri('js/grayscale.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);`

to

`wp_enqueue_script('jquery-easing', get_template_directory_uri(). '/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-easing', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/grayscale.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true);`

Please make sure the path get_template directory_uri() will return you 
http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/yourtheme you need to add rest of the path preceded by "/".

Hope this help you!

Comment: still no joy, I am working on a local MAMP server, does that make a difference?

Comment: No it doesn't. Can you tell me what error are you getting now?
Also can you provide me Screenshot of enqueue JS URL from inspect or view source?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in the console. although the scripts look fine in the footer.. afraid i cant see how to add screen shots

Comment: Install lightshot get screenshot and upload to cloud of lightshow. It generates url. Just paste it here. Or take a screen shot and upload here. (https://prnt.sc/) and send me the URL.

404 for what resource you're getting.

Comment: I guess you have removed script tags from footer and in footer.php file of the theme you have called get_footer() function. The code you have added will be called through get_footer() functions. I want you to double check through view source of the page that jquery.js is included or not, JS files which you enqueue in functions.php file are showing up or not.

Comment: i have removed script tags from the footer now...  the header looks like this now https://prnt.sc/pc1txb

Comment: I have used wp_deregister_script('jquery'); to remove WP standard jQuery.

Comment: I'm still not getting required info. Can you save the whole source code from view source into text file and upload here?

Comment: Please don't de-register WP jquery library.

Comment: don't think i can upload a text file??

Comment: I managed t get on script to load using  function add_custom_script() {
        wp_register_script('custom_script', get_theme_file_uri() . '/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js', array( 'jquery' ));

        wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
    }

Comment: I added <?php
  wp_footer(); ?> to the footer.php file and now the jquery is working.. thank you for help

Comment: ahh.. I told you yesterday but mistakenly I wrote get_footer instead of wp_footer(). It's better you use default WP template with it's default function.
Good luck for further theme integration!

Comment: Please do mark the answer accepted for other member who come and check and read all the conversation and get help out from this. Thanks!

Comment: can see any buttons to accept the answer...just the red flag?